# Non-positivity of a quartic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, optimization

Let

$$f(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4):=\left(1-\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)
   (\alpha -3) \xi _3 \xi _1^3-2
   (\alpha -2) \xi _2 \xi _3 \xi
   _1+c_1 \left(\xi _1^4 (\alpha
   +\beta -3)+3 \xi _2 \xi
   _1^2\right)+c_2 \left(\xi _2
   \xi _1^2 (\alpha +\beta
   -2)+\xi _3 \xi _1+\xi
   _2^2\right)+c_3 \left(\xi _1
   \xi _3 (\alpha +\beta -1)+\xi
   _4\right)-\xi _3^2=\left(1-\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)
   (\alpha -3) \xi _3 \xi _1^3-2
   (\alpha -2) \xi _2 \xi _3 \xi
   _1+c_1 \xi _1^4 (\alpha
   +\beta -3)+\xi _2 \xi _1^2
   \left(c_2 (\alpha +\beta
   -2)+3 c_1\right)+\xi _3 \xi
   _1 \left(c_3 (\alpha +\beta
   -1)+c_2\right)+c_2 \xi
   _2^2+c_3 \xi _4-\xi _3^2$$

be a polynomial of order $4$. Then do there exist $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that for some $\alpha$, $\beta>0$, we have $f(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4)\le 0$ for all $\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,\xi_4\in\mathbb{R}$? If there do exist such $c_1$ and $c_2$, then what's the restrictions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

It seems to me that the coefficient of $\xi _4$ must vanish, i.e. $c_3=0$. Also, this seems to be a decision problem. Any good reference (in particular, a systematic approach to decision problems), suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Do you intend to treat $c_3$ together with $c_1$ and $c_2$?

Comment: Yes. First we find $c_3=0$.

Comment: Have a look at Newton polygon and S.O.S. (Sum Of Squares).